# Dynamically name terraform modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am writing a python script which will in turn trigger a terraform modules and created the needed resources in AWS.
From python script ill be passing the account id for aws account. which will be used to as a variable for terraform.
Now the issue i am facing is everytime when i run the python script ill give a new account id.
but since terraform works on one-to-one module name to resource associted mapping. the presciding resource is getting destroyed and new one is getting created
So is there any way to make the name of the modules dynamic so that presciding resources dont get destroyed
Here is the code block to give more idea
This is the modules here the account id is sent from python script:

```
`module "example" {
source = "./modules/endpoint_services_allow_principle"
service_id = data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.selected.service_id
accountId = var.accountId
}`
```

I was expecting the make the modules name dynamic so that the existing resources creates via terraform dont get deleted

Comment: if you are only interested in creating infrastructure, and not managing infrastructure, then you may want to consider different tools besides Terraform (such as an imperative executor and not a declarative executor).

Comment: I will agree with @MattSchuchard, however as a workaround, you could smartly play with the state file. So with every new account, you have to change the key of the remote backend (if using).
Each account has to go through the process of `init/plan||apply` so that backend can be configured and nothing happens to the last provisioned state. `terraform init -backend-config key=$VALUE` is the command to configure the backend on the fly. You can avoid Key config in your s3 remote backend config.

Answer (score 2):

A `module` block can optionally describe multiple dynamic instances of the child module systematically, if you use the special [`for_each` argument](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each).

To achieve that, you'd change your Python script to create or update a definition of *all* of the instances that should exist. You can pass that to Terraform as an input variable of a set type, declared like this:

```
variable "allowed_account_ids" {
  type = set(string)
}
```

Then you can tell Terraform that there should be one instance of the module for each element of that set:

```
module "example" {
  source   = "./modules/endpoint_services_allow_principle"
  for_each = var.allowed_account_ids

  service_id = data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.selected.service_id
  account_id = each.value
}
```

If you set `var.allowed_account_ids` to `["1234", "4321"]` then this would declare two instances of the module, with the following addresses:

- `module.example["1234"]`
- `module.example["4321"]`

You can create a new instance by adding a new unique element to `var.allowed_account_ids` *while keeping all of the existing ones*.

You can remove an instance by removing one of the existing elements from `var.allowed_account_ids`, in which case Terraform will notice that your actual state has an instance of the module that your configuration doesn't describe, and so will propose to delete it.

Terraform is a "desired state" system, so you must always describe everything that should exist within the scope of this configuration, including everything that was created on previous runs. The continued presence of account IDs added earlier is how Terraform knows that you intend for that module instance to still exist, rather than for it to be deleted.